# How to display arabic correctly in Spring JSF MySQL application?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jsf-2, heidisql

i am using **spring 3**, **JSF 2** , **MYSQL**, **Hibernate**, and Heidi SQL is the GUI tool for the database
and i am having an encoding problem with Arabic characters is that Arabic words is inserted in the database as `??????????` and appears in the view in the same form.

so here's my encoding configuration:

**1- Database:**

- **Character set**: utf 8
- **Collation**: utf8_general_ci

**2- Spring:**

i am using the following filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

**3- JSF:**

As far as i know: Facelets uses `UTF-8` by default.

**4- Hibernate:**

here's the connection url for the database:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8
```

please advise if i am missing something in the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `characterEncoding=UTF-8` parameter in your JDBC URL. Here's the revised JDBC URL with the minimum required parameters to let it handle UTF-8 properly:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: thanks a lot it works fine, any ideas how to configure that through xml properties ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with XML properties.

Comment: i meant adding encoding configuration in separate properties not in the connection url as : `<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>`

Comment: I have no idea. Ask a new Hibernate-targeted question.

Answer (score 1):

if you use tomcat you will need to add the following argument to configuration Arguments:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

in addition to the above hibernate configuration.